# My scratchbox 2 installation is using an ARM gcc build to compile for the ARM target. How do I fix this?

Tags: cross-compiling, maemo, scratchbox

I'm using scratchbox 2, the maemo development cross-compilation environment. When compiling code for the ARM target, I think scratchbox 2 is using the native ARM gcc compiler, which runs very slow on my x86 machine.

I think it should be using an ARM cross-compiler, compiled for x86, that runs much faster.

Sorry for the lack of details for now, but is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You can't run an ARM program on an x86 machine without an emulator... (which I doubt you have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wrestling with this for a really long time, it seems the best solution is to simply reinstall Scratchbox 2.

Make sure to delete the following directories:

```
~/.maemo-sdk
~/.scratchbox2
/opt/maemo
```

And then run:

```
apt-get install maemo-sdk --reinstall
```

And then install scratchbox2 however you did before.